Document R6 static method with Roxygen
I have an R6 class with a static method (analagous to a C# or Java static method). Code works fine. I want to document the static method with Roxygen2, but cannot find how to do this.
#' Test class
#' @description
#' Just for demo purposes
#' @export
TestClass <- R6::R6Class(

    ' Detail unimportant
)
#' TestClass$Is
#'
#' Static method to test whether x is a TestClass object
#' @param x An object to test
#' @return TRUE iff x is a TestClass object
TestClass$Is <- function(x){

    return (any(class(x) == "TestClass"))
}

Using devtools::document() I get the error message:

✖ TestClass.R:25: Block must have a @name.
ℹ Either document an existing object or manually specify with @name

I have tried inserting various name, title, and other tags with no success. Can someone please advise. Thank you.

any(class(x) == "TestClass") is not a good way of testing for a class type. Instead, use inherits(x, "TestClass"). It’s shorter and more robust.

Another thing: “static” methods aren’t really a thing in R6, and are completely unnecessary in R in general. Languages like Java And C# need static methods to because they don’t allow functions outside of classes; static methods are essentially a hack to get around this limitation. In languages where you can have functions outside of classes, static methods are essentially not needed (though C++ has them anyway).

Thank you for your observations - I like inherits...

Static functions and data are a useful way of maintaining state, etc common to all instances of a class. Its not a hack. In an OO world why would you use global functions/data for this?

Non-static doesn’t man “global”. You can still maintain local state in non-global functions but, true, it requires you to faff around with environments. But the same is true with R6. At any rate your function does not manage any data. (Though you’re right that in C++, C#, Java etc. static methods then give you the benefit of information hiding by making the data private.) But I’ve glossed over one other potential advantage of static functions, which is discoverability via intelli-sense autocomplete (i.e. you get it listed when you type ClassName$).

Thanks to all. I found an answer to my question is the correct placement of the relevant name tag.
#' TestClass$Is
#'
#' Static method to test whether x is a TestClass object
#' @name TestClass$Is
#' @param x An object to test
#' @return TRUE iff x is a TestClass object
TestClass$Is <- function(x){

This documents the function, but unfortunately not as a member of the class.

As far as I know those aren't supported by Roxygen, but then they aren't really static methods, since they don't work on instances of the class.  I'd suggest just using a naming convention on a regular function, e.g.
TestClass_Is <- function(x){
    return (any(class(x) == "TestClass"))
}

